# por que me da error trabajar con node y archivos en ambiente mac

Tags: nodejs, macos

estoy trabajando en un proyecto que en sistema operativo windows funciona bien, pero cuando me cambie a mac ya las funciones que tienen que ver con archivos dejaronde funcionar recibiendo un error con status 400 y al querer imprimir el error es undefines. pongo esta funcion como ejemplo, pero todas las funciones del proyecto que tienen que ver con archivos o documentos me generan el mismo error. ya intente correr el proyecto con sudo pero sigue apareciendo. cambie a usar pipeline y funciono pero el proyecto es muy grande para cambiar todas las funciones. estoy usando node en su version 10.16.3. gracias de antemano cualquier ayuda

```
    fileSchema.static("createNewDocument", (file: Readable, mimetype: string, originalname: string, size: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!_.isObject(file)) {
      return reject(new TypeError("File is not a valid object."));
    }

    console.log('Write stream opened');
    let gfs = Grid(DBConfig.connFiles, mongoose.mongo);
    let writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
      filename: originalname,
      chunkSize: 1024,
      content_type: mimetype
    });

    writeStream.on('open', () => {
      console.log('Write stream opened');
    });
    
    writeStream.on('error', (errG) => {
      console.log('Error in writeStream:', errG);
      console.error(errG);  este es el error que salta como undefined
      reject(errG);
    });
    
    writeStream.on('close', (fileG) => {
      console.log('Write stream closed successfully');
      let newFile = new FileModel({ file: fileG._id, name: originalname, originalName: originalname });
      newFile.save((error, saved) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error saving FileModel:', error);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log('FileModel saved successfully:', saved);
          resolve(saved);
        }
      });
    });

    file.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`Received ${data.length} bytes of data`);
    });

    file.on('end', () => {
      console.log('File stream ended');
    });

    file.pipe(writeStream);
  });
});
```

Comment: Cómo instalaste node en el mac?

Comment: con homeBrew y nvm

Comment: Windows y Mac usan distinto formato en las rutas de archivos. https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/nodejs-file-paths/ Que formato tiene el string de `filename`?